# Document Library - While uploading the same type of file its not uploading separately

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

In Document Library while uploading the same type of file its not uploading separately. Its getting override.

Example - I've uploaded one excel and one word file in document library. Now If I'm again uploading one excel file in document library its replacing my old excel. Its not getting loaded separate.

If I'm uploading another new type of file like powerpoint, jpg its uploading separate.

When I remove the check box its saying "A file with the name excel - copy.xlsx already exists". Is it possible to upload same file name more than one time without replacing the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, all files in a library need to have unique file names. So either change the file names of the existing files, or the files you are uploading.

Comment: Thanks Robert for the answer. Do you have some good example to create unique column in SharePoint 2013 document library. I've already posted my question with more details in below link. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117855/how-to-use-enforce-unique-values-in-sharepoint-2013-document-library

Comment: @RobertLindgren "All files in a library need to have unique names" is this strictly true?

What about files contained within different folders within a document library?