# How to use "Enforce unique values" in SharePoint 2013 Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

Need help to understand how to use "Enforce unique values" in SharePoint 2013 Document Library.

I have done below steps but its not working.

In SharePoint 2013 --> Created Document Library --> Created Custom Column "Drawing no" --> Selected "Require that this column contains information" "Yes" & Enforce unique values "Yes"

First Step - When I'm filling save value in Drawing No column its giving message "This value already exists in the list"

Second Step - Now I changed the value from 2 to 3 but not able to save the data in document library. Its showing error "The file Test Unique/Excel - Copy.xlsx has been modified by user1".

However Drawing No. 3 is not exists in list. And instead of checking I select cancel option and now duplicate value 2 is showing in Document Library. [image: Print Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer for above question. Providing below link so it will help some one who is facing the same issue.

For this issue, Select the document and edit the properties to make sure the the value of the column is unique, then check out the file. For more details please find below link :-

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a72c5852-9961-48f6-a028-4a50dce38593/how-to-use-enforce-unique-values-in-sharepoint-2013-document-library?forum=sharepointadmin

Answer (score 0):

Since the document is not checked in, it means that the document together with its property values (Drawing No = 2) is only visible to you.

If try to check in the document with Drawing No = 2, then SharePoint wont allow you because as you said, there is already an existing item with Drawing No = 2

Comment: Yes, so can you please help me to know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: In the document library, navigate to Library Settings, then go to Versioning, and at the bottom of the page in the "Require Check Out" choose NO

Comment: Thanks for quick update. I follow above steps and Its already selected No. However still this issue I'm facing.

Comment: Try to check in the duplicate document with Drawing No = 2, it will prompt you

Comment: For duplicate document for both check in and check out its throwing this error  "This list item could not be added or uploaded because duplicate value".

Comment: It is the expected behavior, it wont allow you to checkin documents with duplicate Drawing No = 2; isn't this is your question? This is the behavior of Enforce Unique Values - meaning the column wont allow you to enter duplicate value for that particular column. Hope this helps.

Comment: Got answer for above question. Providing below link so it will help some one who is facing the same issue.                  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a72c5852-9961-48f6-a028-4a50dce38593/how-to-use-enforce-unique-values-in-sharepoint-2013-document-library?forum=sharepointadmin